Combination Sum using Memoiziation
I was working on LeetCode problem 39. Combination Sum:

Given an array of distinct integers candidates and a target integer target, return a list of all unique combinations of candidates where the chosen numbers sum to target. You may return the combinations in any order.
The same number may be chosen from candidates an unlimited number of times. Two combinations are unique if the
frequency of at least one of the chosen numbers is different.
The test cases are generated such that the number of unique combinations that sum up to target is less than 150 combinations for the given input.

As an exercise I wanted to implement memoization, but I could not make it working. So my question is:

How to add memoization ?

If memoization is not possible can i use child process to distribute the calculation and make it faster or is there another way?


Here is the code I started with, and which does not use memoization (note that I used a different function signature than what LeetCode expects):
function countChange(money, coins) {
  const result = [];
  function recurse(start, leftOver, selection) {
    if (leftOver < 0) return;
    if (leftOver === 0) {
      result.push(selection);
      return selection;
    }

    for (var i = start; i < coins.length; i++) {
      recurse(i, leftOver - coins[i], selection.concat(coins[i]));
    }
  }
  recurse(0, money, []);
  console.log(result);
  return result;
}

const long_result = countChange(999, [1, 2, 5, 10, 20, 50, 100]);
// const long_result = countChange(4, [1, 2]);
console.log(long_result);

I then tried adding memoization but the results were not correct. Maybe I did not implement it in the right way. Here is the code using memoization:
function countChange(money, coins) {
  const result = [];
  const memo = {};
  function recurse(start, leftOver, selection) {
    if (leftOver in memo) return memo[leftOver];
    if (leftOver < 0) return;
    if (leftOver === 0) {
      result.push(selection);
      // memo[leftOver] = selection;
      return selection;
    }

    for (var i = start; i < coins.length; i++) {
      memo[leftOver] = recurse(i, leftOver - coins[i], selection.concat(coins[i]));
    }
  }
  recurse(0, money, []);
  console.log(result);
  return result;
}

// const long_result = countChange(999, [1, 2, 5, 10, 20, 50, 100]);
const long_result = countChange(4, [1, 2]);
console.log(long_result);


After reading the comments I also tried this, but the result do not match up:
function countChange(money, coins) {
  const result = [];
  // const memo = {};
  const memo = Array(coins.length + 1)
    .fill()
    .map(() => Array(money + 1).fill(-1));
  function recurse(start, leftOver, selection) {
    if (memo[start][leftOver] != -1) return memo[start][leftOver];
    if (leftOver < 0) return;
    if (leftOver === 0) {
      result.push(selection);
      memo[start][leftOver] = selection;
      return selection;
    }

    for (var i = start; i < coins.length; i++) {
      memo[start][leftOver] = recurse(i, leftOver - coins[i], selection.concat(coins[i]));
    }
  }
  recurse(0, money, []);
  console.log(memo);
  console.log(result);
  return result;
}

// const long_result = countChange(999, [1, 2, 5, 10, 20, 50, 100]);
const long_result = countChange(4, [1, 2]);
console.log(long_result);


Your link is not pointing to where you intended. But please include the description of what the aim is of "combination sum".

@ShahramAlemzadeh, I am asking the asker to edit their question and include a description.

If your code uses both start and leftOver, you have to memoize on the combination of start and leftOver. As it stands now, you're pulling out an answer based on leftOver that was for some other start.

@trincot sorry i miss clicked, the link that i wanted to add was this:
https://leetcode.com/problems/combination-sum/description/

@btilly okay it's more clear for me now, but how will you do it like a nested array like this memo[start][leftover] or something else

Can you include the code challenge description in your question? There is currently a discrepancy between the code challenge referred to and your function and test case. The code challenge limits the coin values and the target to at most 40, while you give an example with 999. The parameters are in the opposite order. Your function returns a number, while the code challenge expects the array. Can you make your question consistent?

Why do you collect selections in  result when in the end you only return a count?

A nested array is an option. Or a nested object. In Python I'd use a dictionary whose keys were pairs. Just as long as you're using all of the arguments that matter to the result, in finding the previously calculated result.

@trincot i was just wondering if it's possible to have a target greater than 40 but i know it was initially limited, i updated my code i return an array now

@btilly I tried doing it but i think i'am missing something, i added the code to the descriptions Thanks in advance

There are at least two issues:

The memoization should not only happen per leftOver, but also per start, as that determines which coins are still available, and that obviously influences what is still possible.

When you use memoization, you should make the recursive function only depend on those two dimensions (start and leftOver), not some selection. In other words, it should return (and memoize) only the selections that are made with coins that are still available. It is the responsibility of the caller to add the selections of earlier coins to that returned set of selections. That way the recursive result is not dependent on earlier selections, and memoization really represents what is selected from a certain point onwards.


Here is your code adapted with those points taken into account:


function countChange(money, coins) {
  // Memo per start index
  const memoPerIndex = coins.map(() => ({}));

  function recurse(start, leftOver) { // Don't pass a selection
    const memo = memoPerIndex[start]; // Get the memo relevant to this start index
    if (leftOver in memo) return memo[leftOver];
    if (leftOver < 0) return []; // Always return an array -- no results here
    if (leftOver === 0) {
      // Return one solution, which has no selections yet, as we only intend
      //    to include coins that are selected from start-index onwards.
      // It is for the caller to extend with selections of other coins.
      return [[]]; 
    }
    const result = [];
    for (var i = start; i < coins.length; i++) {
      for (const recurResult of recurse(i, leftOver - coins[i])) {
        // Extend each result with the current selected coin:
        result.push([coins[i], ...recurResult]);
      }
    }
    memo[leftOver] = result;
    return result;
  }
  return recurse(0, money);
}

const result = countChange(39, [1, 2, 5, 10, 20]);
for (const selection of result) console.log(...selection);



Be aware that when you have more coins and greater amounts, the number of results increase exponentially. For instance,
countChange(215, [1, 2, 5, 10, 20, 50, 100])

...will return over 100000 results, including many results using over 200 coins. This eats quite a lot of memory, and it quickly increases as the target amount increases. Memoization will not reduce the number of results ;-)

If I understand correctly, for the memoization part, you memoize by available coins, so you have a different memo object for each coin. Is memoization effective in this case?
and for the recurResult loop if i understands correctly it maps just the values that have a leftOver equal to 0 ?
Otherwise, I appreciate your solution; it clarified many things for me Thanks!

Yes, if you had earlier chosen the coin with value 1 twice (to sum 2, with leftover = target - 2) and then went on to coin with value 2, then in backtracking you'll end up there again when you start immediately with coin 2 (also with leftover = target - 2), staying at coin 2, benefitting from memoization.
